# iPhone 4S in reboot loop after using Hacktivate tool

Tags: jailbreak, iphone, activation-lock

So, I have an iPhone 4S that I'm trying to run Linux on (no idea if it's possible), and after fiddling with it for a little while I ended up needing to set it up again - which I could not do because it was in iCloud Lock mode, i.e. Activation Lock.

Googling around for a crack to get it out of that mode, I came across a so-called iPhone Hacktivate tool.  That worked fine, or so I thought - the phone is now in an endless reboot loop.

Now, I will not take "bricked" for an answer.  (I might just have to set this project aside for a long time, put it on the slow burner so to speak).

If you guys have any advice on getting it out of the reboot loop that it's in, that would be great.

Key to getting it out of the reboot loop, I think, is getting it into DFU mode so that it can be factory reset or sommat.  I can get it into recovery mode, however since the reboot loop began iTunes hasn't been able to recognize it, and so I'm not sure if I'm successfully getting it into DFU mode.  (Strangely, the process is to hold power+home for 10 seconds, then release power and keep holding home for 10 seconds, but at the same time, the process to hard-reset an iPhone you hold power+home for 6 seconds.  I'm not sure if the hard reset is always part of getting the phone into DFU mode, but it's definitely hard resetting, and iTunes is not reporting a phone in DFU mode.)

EDIT: In case u r wondering, I did not steal this phone.  [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bS7d.png) is a picture of some facebook message history that <s>I obviously doctored</s> should prove it.

EDIT 2: Just saw [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130172/iphone-4-boot-loop-nu-dfu-possible?rq=1), will try.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about running non-Apple software on an Apple device according to [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT 2 was indeed the answer.  I do not know why the phone had to be connected to a computer without iTunes before iTunes would recognize it in DFU mode, but that's what appeared to be the case.

Comment: Thanks for following-up here. Feel free to fill in here anything that may be helpful for someone else with this same issue, and accept your own answer...